# Chrome driver initialized in system path but could not invoke a method

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have ensured that chrome_driver.exe is in my system path but when running the tests getting the below exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.getExecuteMethod()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/ExecuteMethod

at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This is how I solved the issue.... In the build path I added the JARS..:selenium-chrome-driver-2.49.0.jar
selenium-remote-driver-2.49.0.jar.. I had the 2.45.0 versions of the JAR in the build path before.

Answer (score 1):

For both IE and Chrome one needs to include drivers for each using System.setProperty.(Not required for FF)
Drivers can be found here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Just after your main method include below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\\eclipse\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");//2nd parameter would be the path to the driver you downloaded

WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SampleUITest {
 
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
  System.out.println("Chrome driver property:" + System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
  WebDriver wd=new ChromeDriver();
  wd.get("http://www.google.com");
 
 }

}... I suspect some version mismatch between JAR and driver binary.Even this simple test does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below to start chrome browser

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\selenium_setups\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"); //provide location of chromedrive.exe
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("http://URL here");
```

Thank You,

Murali

Comment: any reason why is down voted? i hope stack overflow need to stop down voting.. so that good attitude is maintained. i have no words to use ...down voting with out providing the proper reason is to be avoided.

Comment: Sorry Murali.. Thanks for your time to answer the question I posted. I have set the path properly.